# Is there a way to have particles orientation follow their direction of travel?

Tags: particles

I'm not new to Blender but it seems like it's the first time I need this. I'm using long particles (like tiny sticks) and I would like them to allign to their direction of travel.

I know I can do this with a curve, but what I'm trying to simulate is sparks flying out of a metal object, and I need the particles to be long, not spherical, because I will eventually export this for webgl, and thus simulate some sort of motion blur. So it's a short burst, all very random using a Turbulence force.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just enable "rotation", keep the "velocity" axis (the default), and activate "dynamic" which allows the rotation to be affected by effectors.

[image]

[Documentation here.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/rotation.html)

Comment: Got it! Thank you!